# What is a point of using Commands and Queries in CQRS

Tags: cqrs

CQRS pattern can be implemented in many different ways. The simplest implementation involves splitting service into two, one responsible for writes, and the other for reads:

```
interface IOrdersWriteService
{
    void AddOrder(Order order);
    void DeleteOrder(Order order);
    void UpdateOrder(Order order);
}

interface IOrdersReadService
{
    IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders();
}
```

But for some reason, when people talk or write about CQRS they tend to utilize a Mediator pattern (for example MediatR library) together with Commands and Queries.

So now, instead of having just two services we end up with 8 classes:

```
class AddOrderCommand {}
class DeleteOrderCommand {}
class UpdateOrderCommand {}
class GetOrdersQuery {}

class AddOrderCommandHandler{}
class DeleteOrderCommandHandler{}
class UpdateOrderCommandHandler{}
class GetOrdersQueryHandler {}
```

Surely there must be good reasons for doing this, but it's very hard for me to discern them.

Some seeming benefits that I read about, but don't agree with, are:

1. Single Responsibility Principle - but it's about a reason for the change, and not responsibility per se, so extracting methods to separate classes is not a magical solution.
2. Open Close Principle - I guess it's technically valid, but it's just taking this principle to the extreme. I think that the crux of it is a tad different.
3. Cross-cutting concerns (like logging, security, validation) - I can do it already, using middleware or filters (in .net core specifically, but I'm sure other frameworks offer similar functionality)
4. Loose coupling, because controllers depend only on mediator, and not on a bunch of services - But it was never a big deal to have those dependencies in the Application layer. At least I could see that maybe some controller is getting too big, and depends on too many services. With mediator, it's harder to spot.

Disadvantages:

1. A lot of additional classes
2. What previously was a simple method invocation, now goes through mediator processing queue, not sure how costly it is, but surely not free
3. It's very similar to service locator - global object "to rule them all"

Possible advantages

1. In big projects involving many developers, classes tend to grow and become unwieldy, because everyone just adds some methods here and there. I guess having one class per public method can ameliorate this. On the other hand, we can end up with hundreds or thousands of classes, that previously were one-line methods
2. If there is a need to queue Commands and process them asynchronously (but it still does not make sense to have Queries, as they need to be processed synchronously)

**Can someone name some other benefits of using Commands and Queries, instead of just old-school Services and simple methods?** Specifically people who already work using this pattern (Commands and Queries), would you advocate using it in the next project, and if so, why?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create one class per command, instead you can group related commands together like:

```
public class CommandHandlers : IRequestHandler<CreateOrder, string>,
                               IRequestHandler<AddProduct, string>,
                               IRequestHandler<RemoveProduct, string>,
                               IRequestHandler<CancelOrder, string>
{
    public Task<string> Handle(CreateOrder request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Order created");
    }

    public Task<string> Handle(AddProduct request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Product added");
    }

    public Task<string> Handle(RemoveProduct request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Product removed");
    }

    public Task<string> Handle(CancelOrder request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult("Order cancelled");
    }
}
```

I can think of many benefits, including:

- We get our domain better into our code (capturing behaviour)
- We utilize CQRS to realize that implementing read and write separately has quite some advantages.
- Easier to reason about the code.
- Easier to add cross cutting concerns to the Mediator/Bus, like logging/security....
- Separation of concerns
- The ASP.NET Core/Client frontend is thinner (just send a command...)
  ...